# is on-device speech recognition a thing?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, ios13

New in iOS 13, you're supposed to be able to say this (`import Speech`):

```
let req = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
let loc = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
guard let rec = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale:loc)
    else {print("no recognizer"); return}
print("rec isAvailable says: \(rec.isAvailable)")
if rec.supportsOnDeviceRecognition {
    print("on device recognition")
    req.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
} else {
    print("no on device recognition")
}
```

The trouble is that I get `"no on device recognition"` on all my devices. I can do speech recognition just fine; I just can't do on-device speech recognition. Is this feature real, or is it merely aspirational on Apple's part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely you're running into a known issue with [`supportsOnDeviceRecognition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/3152604-supportsondevicerecognition) on 13.1. From the [iOS/iPadOS 13.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_1_release_notes):

> The [`supportsOnDeviceRecognition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/3152604-supportsondevicerecognition) property always returns false the first time it’s accessed. After a few seconds, accessing it again returns the correct value. (47822242)

Comment: Well, let me ask you this: does your device ever return `true`? If so, what kind of device is it? It would be nice to know what devices can do this, seeing as none of mine can.

Comment: And according to the [iOS/iPadOS 13.2 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_2_beta_release_notes), it's fixed in that version.

Comment: @rickster Same question. Do you have a device that eventually returns `true`? If so, what is it?

Comment: @matt - Unfortunately, I don't have an active development environment I could effectively test this with. I don't see any official or unofficial sources listing specific hardware that supports this functionality.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I'm upvoting your answer because it's very useful — I learned stuff I didn't know — but I can't accept it until I know whether it's right (i.e., whether this is a real feature that just hasn't been working hitherto).

Comment: Yes, this started working on my device when iOS 13.2 came out. Thanks!